# jquery multiple datepicker selected dates not highlighted well

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I would like to know how can i change the styles of highlighted dates in following jquery multiple datepicker.

```
<input id="datePick" type="text"/>

$('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
```

please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/

[image]

Comment: working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3t4j9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3t4j9/4/)</kbd>     [**Read Here on the bottom of the page Tips**](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-highlight a {
    background: #743620; 
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-highlight a {
    background: #red none;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"ui-state-highlight" class is getting added to the  element when any date is selected. we can apply styles to that particular class as shown below:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td.ui-state-highlight {

  // New styles here

}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td.ui-state-highlight a {

 // New styles here
}
```