# Multiple datepicker selected dates want to be highlighted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Already this question is there [jquery multiple datepicker selected dates not highlighted well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916220/jquery-multiple-datepicker-selected-dates-not-highlighted-well)

But im not getting the result for ex : if i selected the date 1 to 10 it want to highlight dates between 1 to 10

I would like to know how can i change the styles of highlighted dates in following jquery multiple datepicker.

Selected dates should be highlighted in differnt color

```
<input id="datePick" type="text"/>
$('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
```

Please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/

Comment: It work fine http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/317/ what you want?

Comment: if i selected the date 1 to 10 it want to highlight dates between 1 to 10 @Sadikhasan

Comment: Do you mean select 1 and 10 then highlight dates between 1 to 10 Am I right?

Comment: yes :) youre are right

Comment: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#pickableRange-demo

Comment: But it is autoselect how can i select manually  ?